# Generating a list from a database and mapping it to an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postman

I am trying to generate a list using a call that can populate a list in Postman from a products table. I have created an object called `ProductSearchList.cs` to hold the list but I am not sure if I have implemented it correctly and how to map the results to the `ProductSearchList.cs` object from `_productrepo`. I have only just started learning EF6 last week.

I need to map the product repo search results to an object named "Henry" in `ProductSearchList.cs` to store the search results.

`ProductSearchList.cs`:

```cs
internal class ProductSearchList
{
    public ProductSearchList Henry = new ProductSearchList();
}
```

IRepository for Products:

```cs
private readonly IRepository<Product> _productRepo;
_productRepo = productRepo;
```

I am having trouble formatting the `CreateResponse` as well:

```
public Response SearchProduct(ProductSearchRequest ProductSearch)
{
    IList<Product> products = _productRepo.Find(x => x.ProductCode.StartsWith("WTP"));
    return Response.CreateResponse();
}
```

Comment: Hello K. Could you please tell us what you are experiencing? I mean are you receiving errors or is the result not what you expect or?? Thanx, Gampa.

Comment: Also, do you just need a list or do you need the data model as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database context and don't need a data model populated (just list) *you could do the following*. If you need a model let us know and I can post some code to select into a data model instead of a list...

```
var ProductList = (from s in HenrysDatabaseContext.Product
                               orderby s.ProductCode
                               where s.ProductCode.StartsWith("WTP")
                               select s).ToList();
```